# REDIS //Benchmark tool// Keys in SET using -r <keyspacelen> do not match in GET

Tags: redis

I am testing Redis (version: 0.8.8.384) using the benchmark tool, and the `redis-server.exe` that is included in the zip package locally. 
I used the following command to test the keyspace_length: 
`redis-benchmark -t set,get -n 4 -c 1 -d 888 -r 1000`

I have managed to capture a tracer (.pcap) locally using `RawCap.exe`.
What I have noticed is that the keys that are send in `SET` command, **do not** match with the keys in `GET` command. I would expect that the used keys are stored somewhere locally and then retrieved from the `GET` command to interrogate the value for each random key.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this behavior is the expected, since you can run a `redis-benchmark` for the `GET` command only:

```
redis-benchmark  -t get -n 4 -c 1 -d 888 -r 1000
====== GET ======
  4 requests completed in 0.00 seconds
  1 parallel clients
  888 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

100.00% <= 0 milliseconds
4000.00 requests per second
```

So each command specified in `-t` is tested independently.

#### Edit

You can pass a lua script to test a set/get in same key. Some thoughts after a post-lunch research :)

- You can turn on `MONITOR` on `redis-cli` before executing this to be sure of what is happening. IMPORTANT: this will kill your benchmarking, just set it to see the actual commands using a small number of tests (e.g. `redis-benchmark -n 10`);
- Since you're loading a lua script, this will be executed **atomically** every time, like if these command were in a `MULTI/EXEC` block;
- You can lock a single random number to be used by both commands by specifying **__rand_int__** parameter **AND** `-r 1000` (e.g.). The `-r` parameter defines the range of random integers used. `__rand_int__` **WON'T** work if you don't specify the `-r` parameter (you can see this when monitoring);
- After turning `MONITOR` off, you can see that for bigger `-n` values the simulation seems to be faster. Try with `-n 10` and `-n 1000` and see if this holds true.
- Read the https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks :)

The script:

```
redis-benchmark -r 10000 -n 1000 eval "redis.call('set',KEYS[1],'xpto') return redis.call('get', KEYS[1])" 1 __rand_int__
```

A sample `MONITOR` output:

```
1487868918.656881 [0 127.0.0.1:50561] "eval" "redis.call('set',KEYS[1],'xpto') return redis.call('get', KEYS[1])" "1" "000000009355"
1487868918.657032 [0 lua] "set" "000000009355" "xpto"
1487868918.657051 [0 lua] "get" "000000009355"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Niloct!

Comment: No problem. You can pass a lua script to `redis-benchmark` too, in theory you could set a random string key and read from the same key in the script if you really need to test it like your question.

Comment: Your comment was very helpful Nicolt!
Do you know if there is a link with guidelines how to achieve that?

Comment: I don't know if your Windows version of Redis will have lua support. If it does then perhaps my edit will help you.